# Mapping over an array of objects, then another array in those objects and getting rid of duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm working on a function that gets an array of objects from an API, in those objects their is an array of tags, I want to return all the tags of those objects to populate a select field in my mark up. This is what I got so far and it's starting to get a bit confusing with all the maps I'm doing, its also returning the values but its returning them the same length of the original array of objects and get rid of any duplicates. What I'm I doing wrong or is their a better way to do this, and I'm using lodash?

```
renderOptions(){
        let dataRef = this.props.designs.items,
            tagArray = [],
            newArr = []
        return(_.map(dataRef, (design) => {
            let tags = design.tags,
                finalArr 
            return(_.map(tags, (tag) =>{
                    tagArray.push(tag)
                    newArr = [ ...new Set(tagArray) ]
                    return(_.map(newArr, (item) => {
                        console.log(item)
                        return( <li><h1>{item}</h1></li> )
                    }))
                })
            )
        }))
     }
```

Comment: are you using lodash or underscore?

Comment: Sorry did I miss that about lodash? I don't understand about duplicates: you do or you don't want duplicates? I'm guessing you don't but just to confirm...

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get rid of duplicates, using the ES6 new Set syntax

Comment: You're re-instantiating newArr on every iteration during the second map.  Are you perhaps intending to use concat? ie: newArr = newArr.concat(...new Set(tagArray));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce` I have made the code more succinct, there's a working version on [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/tikejet/4/edit?js,console). You'll have to adapt that to put in your framework (is it React?).

A good tip is to look out for the return types for lodash methods.
The method `reduce` returns an array so this means we don't need to create a temporary array to hold our value and is assigned straight away to `tags_array`.

```
// assuming your data is something like this...
var objects = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    tags: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    tags: ['b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  {
    name: 'c',
    tags: ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  }
]


var tags_array = _.uniq(                // returns a unique array.
  _.reduce(objects, function(i, o){     // iterates through objects and
    return o.tags;                      // returns o.tags each time
  })
);

console.log(tags_array);
// #=> ["a", "c", "d", "e"]
```

So your function might work something like this, I'm guessing:

```
renderOptions(){
    let dataRef = this.props.designs.items;
    var tags_array = _.uniq(                // returns unique.
      _.reduce(dataRef, function(i, o){     // iterates through objects and
        return o.tags;                      // returns o.tags each time
      })
    );
    return tags_array;
 }
```

Then you could iterate through the array in your view, or adapt the `renderOptions` function to return the li html elements instead.

The `reduce` method can be used too as [Palermo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39395826/1945990) mentioned below:

```
let tags_array = objects.reduce((i, o) => { return o.tags; });
```

so lodash is not needed.

Comment: I completely forgot about reduce, this is a very nice solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need lodash to do this. Here is an even cleaner way to do this

```
let tags_array = dataRef.reduce((i, o) => { return o.tags; });
```

Comment: Brilliant, I'll add to answer